# Understanding The Theorem "If there is a trail, then there is a path"

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I am given the following theorem and proof:

*Statement*

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph, $a,b\in V$, $a\neq b$. If there exists a trail(in $G$) from $a$ to $b$, then there is a path (in $G$) from $a$ to $b$.

*Proof*

[image]

I understand that if the trail is not a path, that means we must have a vertex which occurs more than once, but I don't understand we would have this shorter path? Can anyone explain to be what they're saying here?

Comment: Actually, it is only shown that there is a shorter *trail*. Verify that the removal produces a trail

Comment: In short, suppose some vertex $v$ occurs more than once in the trail.  Then everything between occurences of $v$ can be deleted without affecting the fact that it's still a trail from $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have $x_k = x_m$, where $k < m$, then the part $$\{x_k,x_{k+1}\}, \{x_{k+1},x_{k+2}\}, \ldots, \{x_{m-1},x_m\}$$ in our trail is just a loop, or cycle in graph-theoretic terms, from $x_k$ to $x_k$. Therefore we can remove this cycle from our trail and still have a trail from $a$ to $b$. But this new trail has a shorter length which contradicts our assumption.

Comment: How do we know if we remove the cycle from our trail we will still have a trail?

Comment: We just have to check the part where our cycle was before, because we don't change anything else in the trail. After we delete the cycle, this part looks like $\{a, x_1\}, \ldots, \{x_{k-1},x_k\}, \{x_k, x_{m+1}\}, \ldots \{x_n, b\}$ and it's still a valid trail, because we know $x_k = x_m$ and therefore $x_k$ is a neighbour of $x_{k-1}$ and $x_{m+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

A path has all unique vertices and edges. A trail has only unique edges.

A trail that is not a path repeats vertices. Without loss of generality, it looks like this,

[image: Path that is not a trail]

When, k = 0 or k = n + 1, it looks like this

[image: Edge Cases]

There are saying - let's pick the shortest trail from $a$ to $b$. Their claim is that it must be a path. They are saying "by contradiction, let's assume that it is not a path". Then this cycle must exist. If this cycle exists, then it is no longer the shortest trail. Therefore, the shortest trail must be a path.